# Error on the resulting list of my elemIndices function

Tags: haskell

The function actually works but the list it returns, if the first element is equal to x, won't be in the correct order.

The function:

```
 myelemIndices :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
 myelemIndices x [] = [] 
 myelemIndices x l =  if posic n l == x 
                         then myReverse (n : myelemIndices x (init l)) 
                             else myelemIndices x (init l)
         where n = length l - 1
```

Will return something like:

```
myelemIndices 1 [1,2,1,2,1]
[2,0,4]
```

Posic funtion is equal to :

```
posic :: Int -> [a] -> a
posic 0 (h:t) = h
posic x (a:b) = posic (x-1) b
```

And myReverse does exactly the same as reverse. I'm not looking for a different funtion that works, just a correction on mine. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You're reversing the list every time you find an element. The minimal change here would be to use `myElemIndices x (init l) ++ [n]` instead of `myReverse (n : myelemIndices x (init l))`

Comment: That's the change to just fix it I needed, thanks, as I said above, still a beginner, gotta get used to the prelude and the package modules funcions!

Answer (score 2):

A first anti-pattern in your code is that you use `length`. `length` will usually run in *O(n)* (with *n* the number of elements in the list), but furthermore it is troublesome since the list can have infinite length. In that case `length` will never terminate. In functional programming it is sometimes seen as a sign that something is probably not right.

So the first question is: do we need `length`. What your code needs to do is return the indices. But say you for instance need to know on what pages in a phone book the name "John" is listed, then you do not need to know in advance how many pages the phone book has: you can simply take a look at the first page. In case it has a person with first name John, then you say that is on page 1, and regardless of that, you move further.

We can use the same approach here. The only thing we need is a *parameter* that keeps track of the page we are currently looking at. We can introduce this parameter by defining a *new* function that will do most of the work. So:

```
myElemIndices :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
myElemIndices x l = go 0 l
    where go = ...
```

So we defined a function `go`, and the first parameter will keep track of the page number. We will need to update that number in case we do recursion. But now of course we still need to define the `go` function.

The base case is easy: in case we reached the end of the list (phone book), we can say we will not find any occurences anymore. So we can write:

```
go _ [] = []
```

This thus means that, regardless of the page number (`_`), in case there are no pages anymore (`[]`), we return an empty list as match `[]`.

In case we did not reach the end of the phone book, we can fetch the head `h`, and the tail `t`. We will have to check if the head `h` matches with the queried element `x`. In case it does, we return the page number, otherwise we don not. Regardless of that, we keep searching for more pages. So we can write:

```
go i (h:t) | x == h = i : <next-matches>
           | otherwise = <next-matches>
```

the `<next-matches>` simply is a recursive call where we update the page number (`i+1`), and we continue with the tail of the list, so:

```
go i (h:t) | x == h = i : tl
           | otherwise = tl
    where tl = go (i+1) t
```

Now we can put that all together into:

```
myElemIndices :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
myElemIndices x l = go 0 l
    where go _ [] = []
          go i (h:t) | x == h = i : tl
                     | otherwise = tl
              where tl = go (i+1) t
```

We can still improve the code a bit. First of all, we do not have to write:

```
myElemIndices x l = go 0 l
```

Notice that both the head and the body end with `l`. We can omit this, and turn it into:

```
myElemIndices x = go 0
```

Furthermore we do not need the result to be `Int`s as well. As long as these are `Num`s, we are fine. So we can generalize this to:

```
myElemIndices :: (Eq a, Num n) => a -> [a] -> [n]
myElemIndices x l = go 0 l
    where go _ [] = []
          go i (h:t) | x == h = i : tl
                     | otherwise = tl
              where tl = go (i+1) t
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the perfect answer. Although I'm only starting in haskell, it is 100% understandable and indeed a very interesting (and optimal) way to do it, will definitely read it a few times and understand how it goes.